# Sorting unordered_map in reverse by value

Tags: c++, dictionary, sorting, unordered-map

I'm trying to reverse sort an `unordered_map<int, int>` by its values and I don't understand why it's not working properly.

This is the code I'm using:

```cpp
static bool comp(const pair<int,int>& a, const pair<int,int>& b) { return a.second < b.second; }

unordered_map<int,int> sort_map(unordered_map<int,int>& m) {
    vector<pair<int,int>> v;
    unordered_map<int,int> sorted_m;
    for (const auto& it : m) {
        v.push_back(it);
    }

    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),comp);

    std::cout << "sorted vector:" << std::endl; 
    for (const auto& it : v) {
        std::cout << it.first <<":" << it.second <<std::endl;
        sorted_m.emplace(it);
    }

    return sorted_m;
}
```

This is an example input for the map: `[5,-3,9,1,7,7,9,10,2,2,10,10,3,-1,3,7,-9,-1,3,3]`
And this is the output:

```
sorted vector:
-9:1
1:1
-3:1
5:1
-1:2
2:2
9:2
10:3
7:3
3:4

sorted map:
3:4
10:3
9:2
2:2
-1:2
5:1
-3:1
1:1
7:3
-9:1
```

As you can see the vector got sorted correctly, but when I use `emplace()` the order gets messed up (`7:3` should be after `10:3`). Why is this happening?

Comment: Even if this would work you end up with very fragile code, the moment your vector reallocates your map is broken (full of dangling references).

Comment: Are you trying to hold the result of the sort in an ***unordered*** map? You do realize that an UNORDERED map is *not ordered*, right? Or am I missing something? Where is the code that produces the second half of your output?

Comment: *This is an example input for the map:* -- You should post a [mcve] instead of having others to create a `main` program.

Comment: You should not expect that a container that is named `unordered_map` keeps its elements in any particular order.

Comment: Not what you are asking about but you can great simplify your code, those for loops are not needed. `vector<pair<int,int>> v(m.begin(), m.end());` That one line copies `m` to `v`. and in the same way `unordered_map<int,int> sorted_m(v.begin(), v.end())` will copy `v` to `sorted_m`.

Comment: You may want to return the sorted vector (or a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)), if you want to keep the order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't control the order of elements in an `unordered_map`. It isn't the insertion order. The order of elements in a map is unspecified, and can be different between runs of your program, and between different insertion patterns of the same data.

You were unlucky enought to see a case that was *nearly* the order that you wanted, making you think it was possible.

Comment: Being picky here, but "implementation-defined" means that the compiler manual must document exactly what happens. This is really not required, making the order merely "unspecified".